# History.replaceState not working properly

Tags: html, browser-history

I need to append tab name in the browser url on tab click.
I have used `History.replaceState('','','newpath');`

**Example:**

```
History.replaceState('','','localhost:8000/mypage.com/home');
```

Now suppose I have open the page using home tab. After that when ever I'm changing the tab, the tab name is changing for sometime in the url  and after that its changing back to home tab.

Comment: can you be more specific, not getting it

Comment: onpage load suppose i have url like: History.replaceState('','','localhost:8000/mypage.com/home');Once clicked on next tab suppose "about" then browser url is chaning to localhost:8000/mypage.com/about and its changing back to localhost:8000/mypage.com/home

Comment: You want to change URL